# How is $\arctan(\sinh(x * \pi))$ the inverse of $\log(\tan(x)) / \pi$

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

How is $$\arctan(\sinh(x * \pi))$$ the inverse of $$\frac{\log(\tan(x))}{\pi}$$

What is the relationship between $\log(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$. I guess is what my real question is.

Comment: Hint: what's $\sinh$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Inverse_functions_as_logarithms. I have been looking at this and scratching my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not. The inverse of your function $y(x)=\arctan(\sinh(\pi x))$ is $y^{-1}(x)=\dfrac{\sinh^{-1}(\tan y)}\pi$ , where $\sinh^{-1}(t)=\ln\Big(t+\sqrt{t^2+1}\Big)$.